# Python implementation of quicksort

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to implement a quicksort in python and I simply cannot get my head around what's wrong with the following code:

```
def partition(myArray, start, end):
    pivot = myArray[end]
    pIndex = start
    for i in range(0, end+1):
        if myArray[i] <= pivot:
            myArray[i], myArray[pIndex] = myArray[pIndex], myArray[i]
            pIndex += 1
    myArray[pIndex], myArray[end] = myArray[end], myArray[pIndex]
    return pIndex

def quicksort(myArray, start, end):
    if start < end:
        pIndex = partition(myArray, start, end)
        quicksort(myArray, start, pIndex-1)
        quicksort(myArray, pIndex+1, end)


exampleArray = [7, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5, 3, 4]
quicksort(exampleArray, 0, len(exampleArray)-1)
print(exampleArray)
```

Apparently the maximum recursion depth is exceeded within the for loop of the partition function. I am not sure, but I think it has sth to do with python's way of not counting the last entry of range(). I have tried every combination tho.

I know, this is maybe too specific to ask in a forum, but I am completely stuck. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: been a while since I haven't implemented this, but shouldn't the partition loop be `for i in range(start, end+1):` ?

Comment: @Cid: thx soooo much!!! Turns out it is `for i in range(start, end)`. Wow, can't believe I just couldn't see this